# Toupper not working with char array

Tags: c

Thanks for your attention... I am really confused.. Why I cannot convert char type to uppercase with toupper when I gave the char an array... like this "char drh[1]"?

Here is my code.. This code is not finished yet.. I'm stuck in the midway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char nama[50], gender[6], drh[1];
    int tahun_l, usia;
    float berat, tinggi, berat_i;

    printf("Masukkan Data Anda\n\n");
    // INPUT ZONE

    //First
    printf("Nama\t\t\t\t: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", &nama);

    printf("Tahun Lahir (yyyy)\t\t: ");
    scanf("%d", &tahun_l);

    printf("Gol Darah (A/B/C)\t\t: ");
    scanf("%s", &drh);

    system("cls");

    //Second
    printf("Masukkan Data Anda\n\n");

    printf("Nama\t\t\t\t: %s\n", nama);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Tahun Lahir (yyyy)\t\t: %d\n", tahun_l);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Gol Darah (A/B/O)\t\t: %s\n", drh);
    drh = toupper(drh); //not working
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Jenis Kelamin (Pria/Wanita)\t: ");
    scanf("%s", &gender);

    printf("Berat Badan (kg)\t\t: ");
    scanf("%f", &berat);

    printf("Tinggi Badan (cm)\t\t: ");
    scanf("%f", &tinggi);

    //FORMULA ZONE
    usia    = 2008 - tahun_l;
    berat_i = tinggi - 100 - (0.1 * (tinggi - 100));
    //OUTPUT ZONE
    printf("\n%s, berdasarkan data yang Anda masukkan,\n", nama);
    printf("Anda berjenis kelamin %s, saat ini Anda berusia %d tahun,\n", gender, usia);
    printf("Berat badan = %.2f kg, tinggi badan = %.2f cm, golongan darah = %s \n", berat, tinggi, drh);
    printf("\nBerat badan ideal adalah %.2f", berat_i);

    getche();
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I got this error @IonutHulub
 [Error] invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

Comment: looks like you got your answer to that question. also, replace `scanf("%s", &drh);` with `scanf("%c", &drh);` cause if you read a string scanf is also going to add a '0' at drh[1] and that might result in memory corruption.

Comment: @IonutHulub thanks for your reply.. I have already changed it into scanf("%c", &drh).. but it goes to runtime error.. I really confused s I changed it into scanf("%s", &drh);

Comment: It does not work either @IonutHulub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toupper` function works on a single character, not on a string. If you need to convert the whole string to upper case, you need to use a loop:

```
for (char *p = drh ; *p ; *p = toupper(*p), p++)
    ;
```

However, your `drh` buffer does not have a sufficient length: it must have 2 characters to fit the null terminator:

```
char nama[50], gender[6], drh[2];
//  Add 1 char for terminator ^---- HERE
```

Moreover, since you know that `drh` is a single character, you can use

```
*drh = toupper(*drh);
```

Comment: aieee! Don't put a postincrement inside a call to `toupper`, it's a macro and it might evaluate its argument more than once.  (I don't remember if the C standard says it's allowed to do that or not, but there definitely have been C implementations where it did that.)

Comment: @Zack You're right, saving a few characters is not worth risking the error here.

Comment: Oh I see.. Thanks for you help everybody :D.. Thanks for your help @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 2):

The function `toupper` takes a single character and you are passing it an array of characters (yes, `drh[1]` is an array of one character). This line of code will never work with arrays:

```
drh = toupper(drh);
```

since you can't copy arrays like that. You are probably confusing a single `char` with a `char[1]`. You only have one option and that is to change the declaration of `drh` to `char drh;`.

And you will want to change this line of code:

```
scanf("%s", &drh);
```

to:

```
scanf("%c", &drh);
```

since you are reading a character not a string.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Marlon... I've changed the char drh [1] to char drh... but it doesnt working too... It worked when I delete variable char name[50], gender[10]..So when there is an char array type, it does not working

Answer (score 0):

`toupper` works on *individual characters*, but you are trying to apply it to an entire array.  The compiler should have complained about converting integers to pointers and back or something like that -- if it didn't, stop right now and turn warnings on.

To uppercase an entire "string" (nul-terminated character array) in C you have to loop over the characters yourself, like so:

```
for (char *p = drh; *p; p++)
  *p = toupper(*p);
```

That is the most idiomatic way to do this, but let me also write it a different way that may make it clearer what's going on:

```
char *p = drh;
while (*p != '\0')     // until we reach the end of the string
{
    *p = toupper(*p);  // upcase the character currently pointed to by 'p'
    p++;               // advance to the next character
}
```

**EDIT:** I failed to notice that you are passing a *one-character* array to `scanf`.  That will inevitably corrupt your stack, because even if the user cooperates and types only one character, `scanf` will write *two* characters to the array (the character the user typed, and the obligatory NUL terminator).  You need to make that `char drh[2]` if you want to use `scanf("%s")` to read one character.  And even that won't help when (not if) the user types more than one character; the *proper* way to write this program would use `fgets` (or, better, `getline`) to read entire lines and then munch them by hand (i.e. *not* with `sscanf`).  Basically in the long term you want to forget you ever heard of `scanf` or its relatives.  I wouldn't blame you for wanting to solve one problem at a time, though.

Comment: Now I understand why my I code run into Runtime error.. Ok thanks for you help @Zack.. I will try this code :D